# How would I execute this code sequence

Tags: java

The original code is:

```
  public class A;
{
  private int number;
  protected String name;
  public double price;

  public A( )
  {
    System.out.println( "A( ) called" );
  }

  private void foo1( )
  {
    System.out.println( "A version of foo1( ) called" );
  }

  protected int foo2( )
  { 
    System.out.println( "A version of foo2( ) called" );
    return number;
  }

  public String foo3( )
  { 
    System.out.println( "A version of foo3( ) called" );
    return "Hi";
  }
}

  public class B extends A
{
  private char service;

  public B( )
  {
    super( );
    System.out.println( "B( ) called" );
  }

  public void foo1( )
  {
    System.out.println( "B version of foo1( ) called" );
  }

  protected int foo2( )
  {
    int n = super.foo2( );
    System.out.println( "B version of foo2( ) called" );
    return ( n + 5 );
  }

  public String foo3( ) 
  {
    String temp = super.foo3( );
    System.out.println( " B version of foo3( )" );
    return ( temp + " foo3" );
  }
}

  public class C extends B
{
  public C( )
  {
    super( );
    System.out.println( "C( ) called" );
  }
}
```

My question is; I have to execute several code sequences such as:

```
B b1 = new B( );
```

and

```
B b3 = new B( );
int n = b3.foo2( );
```

Where do I place these new code sequences to see what the new output would be? I feel like I am missing something to make the program operational.

Comment: This question seems a bit confusing. Are you saying that you want to know where/how you need to actually call B b1 = new B() and stuff in order to test your code. Seeing as this looks like basic java, you likely need to call it in your main method. Again, don't completely understand.

Comment: Yes, all I was given was this code. I need to figure out how to test the code, so that I can then insert new code sequences to find the new outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just place these 3 classes in 3 distinct files like `A.java`, `B.java`, `C.java`, also specifying a package at the header. Then create a file called something like `Main.java`. This class should have `main` method (**the name and it's signature are important**) like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //do stuff

    }
}
```

This method will serve as entry-point of the app, then just place `B b1 = new B();`, etc. at this method.

Comment: I have separated the classes into seperate files like you said, how do I "specify a package at the header"? I tried  "import A.java;" etc and it threw an error.

Comment: Hmm, I just took the imports out and the program ran... Is that because they are in the same folder together? or because i have all 4 files open in my java editor? I assumed I would need to point to those files within the main.java file somehow?

Comment: If they have no `package` declaration then they are all part of the default, nameless package. `import` is only a way to shorten the full names of classes in Java, so that you can just say `List` instead of `java.util.List`. For the default package, Java will just look in the current directory. (So, yes, it works because they are in the same folder together.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, will save me some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `public static void main(String args[])` method to execute any Java class without being instanced or referenced by other class.

Take a look at this tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a main method, it is the Java standard

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    //Test code here
}
```

Within main you can try things like

```
B b1 = new B();
int n = b1.foo2();
System.out.println("n = " + n);
```